# cannot visit enumerator edit_multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error when I try to edit multiple answers in my form and click save!

```
TypeError (Cannot visit Enumerator):
  app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:61:in `edit_multiple'
```

A User should be able to submit answers several times for the same study and the answers are saved as a study_instance that has the study_id, user_id, and the answers for the questions in that study. 
In the studies controller:

```
def group_answers
@study = Study.find_by_slug(params[:id])
@study_instance = StudyInstance.find(params[:study_instance])
@answers = @study_instance.answers
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { render :json => @study }
end
end
```

In the answers controller I have this:

```
def edit_multiple
  @keys = params[:answer].keys.collect
  @answers = Answer.where(:id => @keys)
  @answers.each { |t| t.attributes = params[:answer][t.id.to_s] }
  if @answers.all?(&:valid?)
    @answers.each(&:save!)
    redirect_to studies_url, :notice => 'Study was successfully changed.'
  else
    return
  end
end
```

And in the group_answers view:

```
.block
  .content
    .inner
      %h2
        = @study.title
      %p.description
        = @study.description
        = @questions
= form_for :answers, :url => edit_multiple_answers_path, :html => { :multipart => true }     do |f|
  - @study_instance.answers.by_position.each do |answer|
    .block
      .content
        .inner
          %p
            = answer.position
            \.
            = answer.question.question_text
            %br/
            = fields_for "answer[#{answer.id}]" do |f|
              - if answer.question.long_text
                = f.text_area :answer_text, :value => answer.answer_text
              - elsif answer.question.short_text
                = f.text_field :answer_text, :value => answer.answer_text
              - elsif answer.question.file_upload
                = f.file_field :answer_image
                %br/
                %span.description 
                  Must be at least 500px x 500px and in gif or jpg format. 
                  %br/
                  No characters other than letters and numbers in file name.
                  %br/
                  Current_file:
                  %br/
                  = answer.answer_image_file_name ? (image_tag     answer.answer_image.url(:thumb)) : "none"
              - else
                = f.select :answer_text, answer.question.options_from_choices, :selected     => answer.answer_text, :include_blank => true

  .group.navform.wat-cf
    %button.button{:type => "submit"}
      = image_tag("web-app-theme/icons/tick.png", :alt => "#{t("web-app-theme.save",     :default => "Save")}")
      = t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save")
    %span.text_button_padding= t("web-app-theme.or", :default => "or")
    = link_to t("web-app-theme.cancel", :default => "Cancel"), studies_path, :class =>     "text_button_padding link_button"
```

I am still new to rails and apoligize if this is something very simple but it has stumped me.

Comment: Can you tel us where is the line 61?

Comment: @answers.each { |t| t.attributes = params[:answer][t.id.to_s] }

Answer (score 0):

I find you code a little bit strange... I think it's better to use nested attributes. You can find the documentation here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html and some example here : http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested.

Comment: yes, the code was written by a previous programmer and I am trying to understand what is happening.  I think the nested attributes may be the solution I am looking for.  I will give it a try and let you know how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: So the problem was with the call to collect and then the call to each.  The solution was removing the collect from the keys.  Still don't really understand but I believe that it had to do with the answers having several keys  that are associated to answer texts with values...if that makes sense.

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"C5Shf6odalxpGC3iUiia+BGhYlzCyomgqyG69F2zVRQ=",
 "answer"=>{"6058"=>{"answer_text"=>"Yes,
 very happy"},
 "6060"=>{"answer_text"=>"He built it in 2 days"},
 "6062"=>{"answer_text"=>"6 hrs"},